# How To Use grep Command In Linux to filter values in a line?

Tags: text-processing, grep, logs

I am trying to read the temperature from my Avalon which has the [Avalon Firmware: 20170603](https://canaan.io/downloads/software/avalon7/openwrt/20170603)

I'm using the command:

cgminer-api -o stats

It brings me a lot of information that I don´t need.

```
root@OpenWrt:/etc# cgminer-api -o stats
STATUS=S,When=1482343577,Code=70,Msg=CGMiner stats,Description=cgminer 4.10.0|STATS=0,ID=AV70,Elapsed=30789,Calls=0,Wait=0.000000,Max=0.000000,Min=99999999.000000,MM ID1=Ver[7411612-6cf14b0] DNA[01313edbc5efabe3] Elapsed[30792] MW[340560 340538 340538 340538] LW[1362174] MH[180 238 259 216] HW[893] DH[2.749%] Temp[30] TMax[77] Fan[5430] FanR[90%] Vi[1201 1201 1202 1202] Vo[4438 4406 4443 4438] GHSmm[8063.47] WU[108083.46] Freq[715.86] PG[15] Led[0] MW0[1170 1302 1206 1250 1197 1312 1331 1262 1300 1216 1230 1281 1265 1273 1327 1291 1232 1231 1267 1292 1286 1203] MW1[1312 1189 1237 1251 1212 1247 1264 1275 1196 1256 1283 1257 1190 1247 1243 1282 1330 1315 1292 1273 1261 1271] MW2[1213 1262 1310 1202 1285 1220 1291 1267 1309 1307 1164 1212 1290 1289 1308 1174 1230 1276 1252 1189 1192 1242] MW3[1302 1275 1209 1307 1217 1294 1328 1273 1237 1256 1227 1239 1268 1242 1308 1314 1296 1314 1331 1324 1297 1190] TA[88] ECHU[512 0 0 0] ECMM[0] FM[1] CRC[974 0 0 0] PAIRS[0 0 0] PVT_T[4-70/0-76/72 0-69/11-76/70 2-70/0-77/74 20-67/0-75/70],MM ID2=Ver[7411612-6cf14b0] DNA[0132c3d0691693b9] Elapsed[30791] MW[340551 340551 340538 340538] LW[1362178] MH[2067 188 222 215] HW[2692] DH[3.629%] Temp[29] TMax[80] Fan[5490] FanR[90%] Vi[1204 1202 1201 1201] Vo[4461 4447 4420 4443] GHSmm[7887.76] WU[103670.36] Freq[700.26] PG[15] Led[0] MW0[1264 1270 1229 1313 1296 1184 1239 1237 1266 1247 1252 1242 1202 1266 1266 1317 1255 1272 1309 1230 1301 1243] MW1[1155 1159 1213 1196 1214 1154 1152 1213 1180 1180 1152 1193 1118 1122 1159 1173 1185 1193 1180 1161 1170 1175] MW2[1269 1138 1285 1180 1256 1210 1170 1299 1223 1185 1164 1132 1140 1225 1246 1173 1237 1212 1192 1284 1215 1205] MW3[762 1268 1187 1271 1277 1150 1202 1208 1172 1170 1176 1249 1177 1154 1197 1250 1176 1227 1268 1218 1262 1251] TA[88] ECHU[0 512 0 0] ECMM[0] FM[1] CRC[0 0 0 0] PAIRS[0 0 0] PVT_T[0-68/10-80/70 19-67/0-76/70 0-70/11-78/72 19-68/0-77/71],MM Count=2,Smart Speed=1,Connecter=AUC,AUC VER=AUC-20151208,AUC I2C Speed=400000,AUC I2C XDelay=19200,AUC Sensor=15483,AUC Temperature=28.17,Connection Overloaded=false,Voltage Offset=0,Nonce Mask=29,USB Pipe=0,USB Delay=r0 0.000000 w0 0.000000,USB tmo=0 0|STATS=1,ID=POOL0,Elapsed=30789,Calls=0,Wait=0.000000,Max=0.000000,Min=99999999.000000,Pool Calls=0,Pool Attempts=0,Pool Wait=0.000000,Pool Max=0.000000,Pool Min=99999999.000000,Pool Av=0.000000,Work Had Roll Time=false,Work Can Roll=false,Work Had Expire=false,Work Roll Time=0,Work Diff=65536.00000000,Min Diff=1.00000000,Max Diff=131072.00000000,Min Diff Count=12,Max Diff Count=18313,Times Sent=1531,Bytes Sent=228345,Times Recv=2668,Bytes Recv=1379612,Net Bytes Sent=228345,Net Bytes Recv=1379612|STATS=2,ID=POOL1,Elapsed=30789,Calls=0,Wait=0.000000,Max=0.000000,Min=99999999.000000,Pool Calls=0,Pool Attempts=0,Pool Wait=0.000000,Pool Max=0.000000,Pool Min=99999999.000000,Pool Av=0.000000,Work Had Roll Time=false,Work Can Roll=false,Work Had Expire=false,Work Roll Time=0,Work Diff=16384.00000000,Min Diff=4096.00000000,Max Diff=16384.00000000,Min Diff Count=374,Max Diff Count=993,Times Sent=109,Bytes Sent=12038,Times Recv=119,Bytes Recv=12214,Net Bytes Sent=12038,Net Bytes Recv=12214|STATS=3,ID=POOL2,Elapsed=30789,Calls=0,Wait=0.000000,Max=0.000000,Min=99999999.000000,Pool Calls=0,Pool Attempts=0,Pool Wait=0.000000,Pool Max=0.000000,Pool Min=99999999.000000,Pool Av=0.000000,Work Had Roll Time=false,Work Can Roll=false,Work Had Expire=false,Work Roll Time=0,Work Diff=0.00000000,Min Diff=0.00000000,Max Diff=0.00000000,Min Diff Count=0,Max Diff Count=0,Times Sent=2,Bytes Sent=151,Times Recv=3,Bytes Recv=244,Net Bytes Sent=151,Net Bytes Recv=244|
```

But I just need this values:

```
 Temp[29] TMax[80] Fan[5490]
 Temp[29] TMax[80] Fan[5490]
```

I tried with this two commands but they didn´t work

```
1.- cgminer-api stats | grep "^ *\[temp_avg]"
2.- cgminer-api stats | grep temp
```

Comment: Why does the question specify "grep" when you don't really care which tool is used (and, f/e, are willing to accept an answer that uses awk)? Not so much the case with OpenWRT where you only have busybox ash as an available shell, but in many questions of this nature the best approach uses only native bash builtin functionality (ie. `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` matching to populate `BASH_REMATCH`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$ grep -oE 'Temp[^F]*Fan\[[[:digit:]]+\]' text
Temp[30] TMax[77] Fan[5430]
Temp[29] TMax[80] Fan[5490]
```

#### How it works

- `-o` tells grep to print only the matching text and not the rest of the line.
- `-E` tells grep to use extended regular expressions.  (The default basic regular expressions are archaic.)
- `Temp[^F]*Fan\[[[:digit:]]+\]`

  This regex matches any string that starts with `Temp`, followed by any number of characters that don't include `F`, followed by `Fan` followed by a literal `[`, followed by one or more digits, followed by a literal `]`.

Comment: Your output does not match the requested output -- specifically, the percentage value not mentioned as desired output.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks.  You are right.  I must be going blind.

Comment: Thanks. It is true that the desired output is not in the answer but I think I can figure out how it is done. Although it would be great that you edit your answer. Thanks bought

Comment: @mavi I updated it with your desired output.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like the requested fields are the eighteenth, nineteenth, and twentieth fields as separated by whitespace, so:

```
$ awk '{ print $18, $19, $20 }' /path/to/input
Temp[30] TMax[77] Fan[5430]
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
grep -o 'Temp\[[^]]\+\] TMax\[[^]]\+\] Fan\[[^]]\+\]'
```

Search the input string for:
  `Temp\[` Start with `Temp` and a literal `[`
  `[^]]\+` Not a closing`]`, several times `+`.
  `TMax\[[^]]\+\] Fan\[[^]]\+\]` repeat with TMax and Fan.
And print **o**nly it: `-o`.

Answer (score 2):

General purpose commandline tools like awk, grep and perl are commonly used for this kind of problems. The `cut` command is a minimalistic, purpose built tool for it:

`cut -d\  -f 18,19,20`